# Bash Brace Shell Expansion Fail

Tags: bash, io-redirection, echo, brace-expansion

I have 5 files called `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, `file5`, . I am attempting to run the following command `echo "contents" >> file{1,2,3,4,5}`. I get the following error when I run this command; `-bash: file{1,2,3,4,5}: ambiguous redirect`. My goal is to echo some text to multiply files in one command. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't redirect to multiple files.  Instead, use `tee -a` (`-a` for "append", since in your question you use the appending redirect operator `>>`):

```
echo "contents" | tee -a file{1,2,3,4,5}
```

Another option is to use zsh instead of bash, which can redirect to multiple files:

```
[birdsnest ~]% echo foo > /tmp/{foo,bar}
[birdsnest ~]% cat /tmp/foo 
foo
[birdsnest ~]% cat /tmp/bar 
foo
```